# Workflow Regular expression fails to check if date is empty

Tags: workflow, regex

I am trying to create a document on a list if a
date list field is set.

So I have a workflow that executes when a list item is changed.
In the workflow, I have set a workflow variable X to `mydate` (`mydate` is returned as string).
Then I have tried the condition : create the element if X is empty. 
But it doesn't work as the element is created in any case (either the date is set or not).

So, I turned to regular expressions.

The check I am using trying:

```
if X corresponds to regular expression  [0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}
   create item in MyLibrary
```

Anyway, this doesn't work as the item in MyLibrary is created either if `mydate` is empty or set to a proper date. ? I have tried others regex that match a date but with no luck.

I am using Sharepoint 2013 with a workflow 2010. If the regular expression  doesn't match a date no item gets created.

Is there anything wrong with my regular expression?

**EDIT:**
in the end I  used `X contains 2`. For 985 years it should be ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empty dates are not as they seem.

Make an action to log the empty date value (assign it to a workflow variable) to the workflow history list for debug purposes, and you'll see a value similar to 1/01/0001.

Once you know that you can check for the substring, and if it matches do whatever else you need to do.